# Change image in ASP.NET with jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

I got this jQuery script:

```
function changeImage(e) {
    var nextImg = $(e).attr('nextImage');
    var oldImg = document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');
    $(oldImg).attr('src', nextImg);

    return false;
}
```

and this ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbOne" Text="1" OnClientClick="changeImage(this); return false;" />
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbTwo" Text="2" OnClientClick="changeImage(this); return false;" />
```

Code behind:

```
lbOne.Attributes.Add("nextImage", "some_image");
lbTwo.Attributes.Add("nextImage", "some_image2);
```

some how it wont change the image src the jQuery script looks okay to me any ideas?

Found the error:

```
var oldImg = document.getElementById('<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');
```

need to add '#' like this:

```
var oldImg = document.getElementById('#<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');
```

works now. thanks for the comments!

Comment: still wont work i checked the source of the page and looked at the liked button it has href:href="javascript:__doPostBack('id','') maybe its because of this? it throws post back?

Comment: I'm not sure you can "override" the client side code of LinkButton.. why not use ordinary `<a>` tags for this?

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered so everyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

Try making a small adjustment so that the postback is completely blocked.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lbTwo" Text="2" OnClientClick="return changeImage(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tested it, but your sample code is missing a qoute after "some_image2 and is missing the imgMain control.

Have you checked in firebug that the JavaScript is firing?
and are you sure your page has a reference to jQuery?

Comment: the quote isnt the problem i just change the image name when i posted the code here probably just missed the quote and imgMain is an asp:Image: <web:Image runat="server" id="imgMain" />

Comment: what is a <web:image control is it not asp:image? or are you using some other add-on to asp.net?

Comment: private library same as asp:Image with diffrent options

Comment: have you debugged the javascript in firebug? to see if the event is firing and the client ids are pickedup correctly?

Comment: found the error it should be like that in the jQuery: var oldImg = $('#<%=imgMain.ClientID %>');  forgot the '#' basic...

Comment: changed it =) to fully use jQuery